# text placement in terminal ruby

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems

Is there a specific gem or any code examples for working with text in the Linux (windows if it is supported) terminals.

I am wanting to create a chat client for a protocol and I want to mimic the style of irssi where it has the status and text input at the bottom, then scrolling text above that, and then if loaded the server list to the right side. All seemingly to float and be fixed in place.

[image]

In this picture you can see at placement 1, there is channel info and STDIN input which is always fixed at the bottom. At placement 2, is the chat. At placement 3, is channel topics and other misc info, and at placement 4, is a channel list that is fixed to the right side.

Is there a ruby gem that allows you to easily do this to a terminal? Even if I have to load my application in screen or some other terminal management to gain functionality I don't mind.

Also is there a way to do this to the windows terminal as well or is this a Linux only function.

Any information would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are two common tools for terminal manipulation.  They are curses and ANSI.  I believe there is a gem for each (more than one) Check [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.org).

Comment: The standard library for cursor addressing on Linux is `curses`. There appears to be a gem called [`rbcurse`](http://rbcurse.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: thanks guys i am currently looking into them.